# Determine Document Base From Route Attribute by Swagger?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, swagger

imagine below controller:

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Swagger.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }


    }


}
```

I want to know how this page is created with swagger.
[image]

and for more information my program.cs file like this which is a simple implementation of swagger:

```
    using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();


var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger(options =>

    {
    });
    app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
    {

    });
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

And how can I make such a this picture for an api without route attributes.For example if you want create a swagger document for another api which is not exist in your project what should you do.

Comment: What Swagger Generator do you use?

Comment: @Ralf I use Swashbuckle.AspNetCore package and this line of code builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
.

Comment: Swashbuckle uses the Attributes to generate the Swagger doc there is no easy way around that. At least not without rewriting parts of Swashbuckles middleware. But those attributes arent bad and you must distingush the HTTP Verbs somehow anyway. Without the attributes i assume your controller doesn't work anyway ignoring swagger. Do you have a special problem with those attributes? You should tell then.

Comment: I just want to have a swagger documentation but the api which i want to document ,doesn't exist in my project. How can I make a swagger document for external api?!

Comment: I'm afraid your requirement can't be implemented, you can see [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio). As you can see, the screenshot you showed is let swagger to scan all the controller actions and then list them in the page, you can't import an external API into this application. By the way this page is loaded when the application is running which means the page is a dynamic page. So you can only integrate it into the application for that external API.

Comment: You can write your own Swagger/OpenAPI documentation(if you know how that API works) and use that via a swagger frontend. But there is no facility that lets you scan an existing reachable public API to generate that automatically. Those APIs just don't surface that info.